# Extant S02 E09 and E12 - Are these citations from other works?

Tags: extant

At the end (about 38:20) of S02E09

> both Terra and Ares put one of their hands in front of a biometric authentication mechanism. The computer says 'system overload' and the door opens.

This feels so absurd that I immediately thought that it was a homage to some other work.
Another scene that puzzles me happens in the middle (around 20:10) of S02E12 where

> TAALR asks Lucy what she had for breakfast

This seems strange since it doesn't appear to have any relation with previous or future events.